# Whats the Swift animate WithDuration syntax?

Tags: swift, swift2, animatewithduration, swift3, optionsettype

I'm porting an older app over to Xcode 7 beta and I'm getting an error on my animations:

> Cannot invoke 'animateWithDuration' with an argument list of type
>   '(Double, delay: Double, options: nil, animations: () -> _,
>   completion: nil)'

Here's the code:

```
 UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.3, options: nil, animations: {
      self.username.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
    }, completion: nil)
```

This works in Xcode 6 so I'm assuming this is an update in Swift. So my question is:

**What's the Swift 3 syntax for animateWithDuration?**

Answer (score 71, accepted):

### Swift 3/4 Syntax

Here's an update with the Swift 3 Syntax:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.3, options: [.repeat, .curveEaseOut, .autoreverse], animations: {
    self.username.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
}, completion: nil)
```

If you need to add a completion handler just add a closure like so:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.3, options: [.repeat, .curveEaseOut, .autoreverse], animations: {
    // animation stuff      
}, completion: { _ in
    // do stuff once animation is complete
})
```

---

*Old Answer:*

It turns out it's a very simple fix, just change `options: nil` to `options: []`.

**Swift 2.2 Syntax:**

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.3, options: [], animations: {
      self.username.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
    }, completion: nil)
```

### What changed?

Swift 2 got rid of the C-Style comma-delimited list of options in favor of option sets (see: [OptionSetType](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_OptionSetType_Protocol/index.html)). In my original question, I passed in `nil` for my options, which was valid prior to Swift 2. With the updated syntax, we now see an empty option list as an empty set: `[]`.

An example of animateWithDuration with some options would be this:

```
 UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.3, options: [.Repeat, .CurveEaseOut, .Autoreverse], animations: {
      self.username.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
    }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Them changing A LOT of stuff in Swift 3 is making it really hard to learn Swift at this point in time.

Comment: @ChrisAllinson I think this suite of changes will be the most extreme. From here on out the changes will be more subtle.

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0.05 * Double(index), usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [], animations: {
    cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
}, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3 Syntax with completion block**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0 , delay: 0.25, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

        // animation
    }, completion: { _ in

        // completion
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 2**

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.1, options: [.Repeat, .CurveEaseOut, .Autoreverse], animations: {
    // animation
}, completion: { finished in
    // completion
})
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.1, options: [.repeat, .curveEaseOut, .autoreverse], animations: {
    // animation
}, completion: { finished in
    // completion
})
```