# UIView.animateWithDuration in Swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation, swift2, xcode7

Before explain my problem, it is important to say that I already implemented the suggestion made in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991822/whats-the-swift-2-0-animatewithduration-syntax) and I think my doubts about this `animateWithDuration` method are quite different, despite both questions having a very similar title.

So, I am a Swift newbie and I am doing some small projects in Swift, based on previous Objective C demos that I did before.

This is my Objective C code:

```
- (void)moveSideBarToXposition: (int) iXposition{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                          delay:0.1
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                     animations:^{  self.mainView.frame = CGRectMake(iXposition, 20, self.mainView.frame.size.width, self.mainView.frame.size.height); }

                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         if (self.isSidebarHidden==YES) {
                             self.isSidebarHidden = NO;
                         }

                         else{
                             self.isSidebarHidden = YES;
                         }
                     }];
}
```

And this is my Swift version:

```
func moveSideBarToXposition(iXposition: Float) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 1.0, options: UIViewAnimationTransition.None, animations: { () -> Void in

        self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(iXposition, 20, self.contentView.frame.size.width, self.contentView.frame.size.height)

    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in

        if isMenuHidden == true {
            isMenuHidden = false
        } else {
            isMenuHidden = true
        }
    })
}
```

And I get this error.

> Cannot invoke 'animateWithDuration' with an argument list of type
>   '(Double, delay: Double, options: UIViewAnimationTransition,
>   animations: () -> Void, completion: (Bool) -> Void)'

I read the documentation  but actually I am not sure what the problem is.

Btw, i am working on Xcode 7 and Swift 2.0

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are passing enum of type `UIViewAnimationTransition` to an argument which requires type `UIViewAnimationOptions` (`options` argument)

Here is the correct syntax with the correct enum value:

```
func moveSideBarToXposition(iXposition: Float) {
    let convertedXposition = CGFloat(iXposition)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 1.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionNone, animations: { () -> Void in

        self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(convertedXposition, 20, self.contentView.frame.size.width, self.contentView.frame.size.height)

        }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in

            // you can do this in a shorter, more concise way by setting the value to its opposite, NOT value
            isMenuHidden = !isMenuHidden
    })
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. In fact, you are right. (my bad, i didn't realize the difference between UIViewAnimationTransition.None and UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionNone). I corrected that line but I still have same problem. I just deleted this line (self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(iXposition, 20.0, self.contentView.frame.size.width, self.contentView.frame.size.height)
) and it all worked. But when I put it back, I get same error that I mention before. Do you have any advice? I would be very helpful

Comment: The error you are getting with the line inserted doesn't really make sense to me, but the problem is that your method `moveSidebarToXposition` takes a argument of type `Float` which you insert to a `CGRect`, which requires type of `CGFloat`. So you need to convert it like this: `let convertXposition = CGFloat(iXPosition)` and use the `convertedXposition` in the `CGRect` construction

Comment: Is it because i must declare that property as a constant? But it works! Thank you!