# UIViewAnimationOptions error migrating from Swift 1 to Swift 2

Tags: swift, uiview

I just updated Xcode to 7.0.1 and therefore also Swift from Swift 1 to 
Swift 2.

I got a lot of errors when the update was done and this is one of the problems I can not fix. It would be really nice if you could fix this for me.

The error message says:

> Nil is not compatible with expected type UIViewAnimationOption'

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 6, options: nil, animations: ({

}), completion: nil)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats the Swift 2.0 animateWithDuration syntax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991822/whats-the-swift-2-0-animatewithduration-syntax)

Answer (score 1):

Use `UIViewAnimationOptions` property object for `options:`

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 6, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in

}, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in

        }) { (finished: Bool) -> Void in

    }
```

or

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse], animations: { () -> Void in

        }, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2 `UIViewAnimationOption` is declared as non optional. Therefore it cannot be `nil`. The equivalent to *no options* is the generic initializer

```
... options: UIViewAnimationOption() ...
```

or a pair of empty brackets

```
... options: [] ...
```