# Error occurred after code migration from swift 2.0 to swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, migration

Can anyone help me resolving this error, just look at the following code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  ...
  ...

  //the following line occurs error: "Ambiguous use of 'startAnimation'"
  **perform(#selector(UIViewAnimating.startAnimation), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.3)**
}
```

How can I fix the above issue?
[image]

Comment: What was the code before migrating to Swift 3.0 ?

Comment: Why do you even call the method like this? Why not just `UIViewAnimating.startAnimation(afterDelay: 0.3)` without going through `perform()`?

Comment: See [How do I resolve “ambiguous use of” compile error with Swift #selector syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658334/how-do-i-resolve-ambiguous-use-of-compile-error-with-swift-selector-syntax) for an explanation of the problem.

Comment: thank you guys! I really appreciate your help~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIViewAnimating` already has a method to start the animation after a delay, you should use this one instead :

```
startAnimation(afterDelay: 0.3)
```

If you insist on using `perform(_:with:afterDelay:)` you can use it like so:

```
perform(NSSelectorFromString("startAnimation"), with: nil, with: 0.3)
```

But keep in mind that you loose compiler safety with this approach, and if you make a typo in your selector your app will crash.

Also, your code is weird because `UIViewController` doesn't conform to `UIViewAnimating`, so unless you implemented the protocol yourself (which would be quite unusual), it's not going to work. It's more likely that you have a method called `startAnimation` in your view controller and that the Swift migrator mistakenly added the reference to `UIViewAnimating`. In which case the correct code would be:

```
perform(#selector(self.startAnimation), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIView` class method.

```
+(void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations



   UIView.animate(withDuration:duration){    
            // code to be executed    
     }
```

look at this UIView method  documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622515-animatewithduration and similar query [Whats the Swift 3 animateWithDuration syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991822/whats-the-swift-3-animatewithduration-syntax)

Comment: thank you for your help, but the first line seems a little bit complicated, i will study what you reply later~

Comment: @K.Zeng please look at those links.